# Use Google Fonts and unicodes

Tags: css

I use "Alegreya" on my website.
Here is my functions.php :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_fonts' );
function enqueue_fonts() {
    wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300i,400,400i,500,700&subset=latin-ext');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
}
```

On my website, the paragraphs and text use Alegreya as expected.
However, I'd like to use the right arrow icon on an :after element.

When I download the font on my computer, it is available as a character under the unicode 'u2192' (I check that in Illustrator).

So, in my CSS, I put :

```
.cta:after{
    content: "\2192";
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

However, the icon displayed is the "Arial" one, and not the "Alegreya", which is much nicer.

How can I use Google Font unicode characters in my CSS ?

Thank you for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Try setting the `font-family` within that block as well.

```
.cta:after{
  content: "\2192";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It still isn't working for me.

Comment: On the Google Font page, we can see that the arrow is not included in the font : https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya
However, it is when I download it on my OS and you tell me that you have it too ? How did you include it in the 'enqueue_font' function ?

Comment: I used the exact same enqueue as you did except for the `&subset=latin-ext` part. Maybe try without that.

Comment: That is how I did the first time, it was exactly the same... Have you installed the font on your serveur before ?

Comment: @GrégoireLlorca not that I remember. It's on my local machine.

Comment: OK, well, I used png files, in the end. Thank you for your help.